# Parse: Find number of objects found in query

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

How do I find the number of objects found in a query? The following code is always printing "0", but there is a user with that username in the database.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"User"];
    [query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:self.usernameField.text];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if ([objects count] == 0) {
            NSLog(@"error %lu", (unsigned long)[objects count]);
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"no error");
        }
    }];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure its Case insensitive?

Comment: The capitalization for the class name and key are correct.

Comment: try to print objects and see what it prints without if else condition

Comment: When I try to print the following line, it just hangs: `NSLog(@"%@", [objects objectAtIndex:0]);`

Comment: You accepted an answer that doesn't follow advised in the Parse documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This , Because parse default user entity is initiated with "_User"

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];

[query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:self.usernameField.text];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)    {

   if ([objects count] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"error %lu", (unsigned long)[objects count]);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"no error");
    }
}];
```

Comment: Why ? there can be number of methods to do a task , parse is doing same at back ...

Comment: Because Parse can update "the back" and _User here is now hardcoded.
Using the actual query makes it less likely to fail on updates. It's also good practice to follow the documentation, because " if you don't know why, they do ".

Comment: Thank  you  @Zil ,  i will care for this in future

Comment: On the same topic, you generally never want to type @"something";,  but use variables, or macros, or anything less... hardcoded :) It's called a "magic string" and you can google about it

Comment: yes i knew , but my intensions was to give a quick answer to him so that he would  able to done work.. :P

Answer (score 1):

Performing a query on the `_User` class should be done using the `+query` method of the `PFUser` class

```
PFQuery *userQuery = [PFUser query];   //Note the difference here.
[userQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)    {
   if ([objects count] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"error %lu", (unsigned long)[objects count]);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"no error");
    }
}];
```